# Is there a leak in the Scroll View Suite sample code by Apple?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks

I need help with the code from [Apple's ScrollViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html); specifically I'm looking at the ThumbImageView class, which doesn't have a dealloc method defined.  I see in the .h that the property for imageName uses retain.

(I wasn't sure if I was allowed to post any code since it's Apple's, so please let me know if I can/should.)

1. Anyway, I thought if we use "retain" that we are responsible for releasing the object reference.
2. The method CreateThumbScrollViewIfNecessary (from the RootViewController implementation file) has a for loop which allocs ThumbImageViews, sets the delegate, and then after adding the thumbview as a subview the a scrollview, proceeds to release the thumbview. If these objects are actually being released, how does the delegate do its job notifying when an image has been tapped, scrolled, etc.

Sorry I'm just so confused.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Either put link of the code you're talking about OR better the code itself... ? Don't assume that everyone will have all the code... or people will search that code from apple site and download it to help you...

Comment: Sorry mihir, I wasn't sure if my pasting in Apple's code was allowed (which is why I asked in my question).  I will paste the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are responsible for clearing the object reference. As far as I can tell, that code of Apple's *would* leak if that property were ever assigned a value.
2. Any view retains its subviews. After each view has been added to the scrollview, the class that creates it has no more use for it so it releases its reference. The object won't actually be deallocated until the scrollview also releases its reference, so the views remain "live" and able to signal their delegates until that happens.

Answer (score 4):

The code leaks. Unfortunately, Apple’s sample code usually leaves a lot to be desired, the design often sucks and there are leaks and glitches. It’s best to take it only as an annotated API reference that shows how various parts of the API fit together, nothing more.